# How to optimise algorithm for Buying Show Tickets when using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I was giving test on some portal where question was as follows:

> A line has formed to buy tickets for a concert.  In order to delay a shortage caused by brokers buying large blocks of tickets, venue management has decided to sell only one ticket at a time. Buyers have to to wait through line again if they want to buy more tickets.  Jesse is standing in line and has a number of tickets to purchase.
>
> Given a list of ticket buyers with their numbers of desired tickets, determine how long it will take Jesse to purchase his tickets.  Jesse's position in line will be stated, and each transaction takes 1 unit of time.  For your purposes, no time is spent moving to the back of the line.
>
> For example, if the zero indexed array of ticket requirements,  tickets = [1, 2, 5] , and Jesse's position p = 1, the first five seconds of ticket sales look like this:

[image: img]

Function Description

Complete the function waitingTime in the editor below. The function must return an integer representing the units of time it takes Jesse to purchase his desired number of tickets.

waitingTime has the following parameter(s):

```
tickets[tickets[0],...tickets[n-1]]:  an array of tickets desired by each person at position tickets[i]

p: Jesse's position in line
```

Constraints

- 1 <= n <= 10<sup>5</sup>
- 1 <= tickets[i] <= 10<sup>9</sup>, where 0 <= i < n.
- 0 <= p < n

Sample Input 0

5
2
6
3
4
5
2

Sample Output 0

12

It took a total of 12 units of time to purchase 2 tickets.

My solution was as follows:

```
function waitingTime(tickets, p) {
    var totalTime = 0,
        l = tickets.length,
        frontPersonStatus;
    while(true) {
        if(p === 0 && tickets[0] === 1 &&  ++totalTime) break;
        frontPersonStatus = tickets.shift() - 1;
        frontPersonStatus !== 0 ? (tickets[tickets.length] = frontPersonStatus) : l -= 1;
        totalTime++;
        p = p === 0 ? l - 1 : p - 1;
    }
    return totalTime;
}
```

*but it runs for some test cases after that it goes all other test cases fails and says  **terminated due to timeout**.b So I think there must be some more optimised solution then this*

[image: test]

Comment: People cheat in interviews and tests, then they complain when they get fired a month later.

Comment: Sir I think, It's a talent as well to bypass the security and cheat

Comment: As someone who interviews and hires for coding jobs, I can say without equivocation that you're wrong @AkhileshKumar. If you're hired for a coding job, no amount of talent for cheating is going to help you hold onto a job you're not qualified for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone standing in front of Jesse has to pay either the same number of tickets or less, everyone behind him has to pay one or more less before Jesse bought all his tickets:

```
  let totalTime = 0;
  for(const [pos, ticket] of tickets.entries())
    totalTime += Math.min(ticket, tickets[p] - (pos > p));
```

Comment: Challenge is already finished. It was just for knowledge where I was failing

Comment: Sir, I cloned their environment for my testing purpose. all thanks goes to u.

Comment: @akhilesh whatever, glad to help :)